# Exercise on power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, power-series

I have solved the following exercise and I would like to know if I have made any mistakes:

Consider the function $g$ defined by the power series $g(x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\dots $.

(a) Is $g$ defined on $(-1,1)$? Is it continuous on this set? Is $g$ defined on $(-1,1]$? Is it continuous on this set? What happens on $[-1,1]$? Can the power series for $g(x)$ possibly converge for any other points $|x|>1$?

(b) For what values of $x$ is $g'(x)$ defined? Find a formula for $g'$.

My solution:

(a) We can rewrite $g$ as $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^{n}}{n}$; we note that $g(-1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cdot(-1)^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{n}$ diverges, by Alternating Series Test $g(1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cdot 1^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ converges (conditionally) so $g$ is well-defined on $(-1,1]$ and it must also converge (absolutely) on $(-1,1)$ so it is also uniformly convergent on each interval $[-c,c]\subseteq (-1,1)$ and hence continuous (since each $g_n(x)$ is continuous) on $(-1,1)$. By Abel's Theorem it is in particular uniformly convergent (and hence continuous as said before) on each interval $[-1+\delta,1], \delta>0$.
If the series converged for some $|x|>1$ then it would also converge (absolutely) on $[-1,1]$, a contradiction, since $g(-1)$ diverges.

(b) $g'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}n\frac{x^{n-1}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}x^{n-1}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^m x^m$ which is well defined for $x\in (-1,1)$ since in that interval the series is absolutely convergent hence convergent. For $|x|\geq 1$ the series does not converge since the summand does not converge to $0$.

Comment: The series does *not* converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$. If it did, it would converge uniformly on $[-1,1]$. The convergence is uniform on $[-1 + \delta, 1]$ for every $\delta > 0$, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer corrected, thanks. Could you please tell me if the rest of the exercise is correct?  Thank you.

Comment: You didn't say how you got from "the series converges for $x = 1$" to "$g$ is well-defined on $(-1,1]$". I can see you know the reason, but you should state it there.